# how to Get cat id and expertise value in my controler

Tags: yii, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

This is my controller and I am trying to get category id and expertise data from my database field. Everything is working, but the problem is that I'm not getting the category id. The problem occurs when I am trying to print all record on my view controller.  here is my part of code  `$cat_id =Yii::$app->request->get('categori_id');`.

```
 //start premium adviser section
    public function actionPremiumsearch()
    {

     if(isset($_GET['login-button1']))
        {
          $model=new UserDetail();  

        $request = Yii::$app->request;

        $post = $request->get();

        $cat_id =Yii::$app->request->get('categori_id');
        //var_dump($cat_id);exit;
        //print_r($cat_id);exit;
        $expertise =Yii::$app->request->get('expertise');
        //print_r($expertise);exit;
                //var_dump($cat_id);exit;


        //$cat = $request->cat_id();
        //echo $cat;
        //print_r($post);
        //$cat_id = $request->get('categori_id');
        //echo $cat_id;
                //$cat_id = $post['categories']['categori_id'];
                //echo $cat_id;exit;
                //print_r($cat_id);exit;


        //print_r($post);
        //$cat_id = $post['categori_id'];
        //print_r($cat_id);
        //$service_id = $post['Service']['id']; 
        //echo $service_id.' '.$expertise.' '.$cat_id;
        //exit;
                     //echo "button1";
        $query = new Query;
                // compose the query
         $query->select('kpt_users.*,kpt_user_details.*,kpt_user_services.*')
                ->from('kpt_users')
                    ->join( 'INNER JOIN',
                        'kpt_user_details',
                        'kpt_user_details.user_id =kpt_users.id'
                    )
                    ->join( 'LEFT JOIN',
                        'kpt_user_services',
                        'kpt_user_services.user_id= kpt_users.id'
                    )


                    //->Where(['kpt_users.user_role_id' =>$role_id,'kpt_user_services.service_id'=>$service_id])
                    ->Where('kpt_users.status = 1') 
                    ->andWhere('kpt_users.user_role_id = 2') 
                    //->andFilterWhere(['like', 'kpt_user_services.service_id', $this->service_id])
                                        //->andFilterWhere(['like', 'kpt_user_details.categori_id', $this->categori_id])
                                         //->andFilterWhere(['like', 'kpt_user_details.expertise', $this->expertise])

                        //->andWhere(['like', 'kpt_user_services.service_id', $service_id])
                     //->andWhere(['like', 'kpt_user_details.categori_id', $categori_id])
                    // ->andWhere(['like', 'kpt_user_details.expertise', $expertise])



                    //->andWhere('kpt_user_details = 2') 
                    //->andWhere(['like', 'categori_id', $cat_id])
                    //->andWhere(['like', 'name', 'alex'])
                    //->andWhere(['like','kpt_user_services.service_id'=>$service_id,'kpt_user_details.categori_id'=>$cat_id])
            ->limit(2);
                // build and execute the query
                $rows = $query->all();
                //var_dump($rows);exit;

         return $this->render('personalinsurance', [
            'result' => $rows,
             'model' => $model,
        ]);


        }

         if(isset($_GET['login-button2'])){
             //echo "kanak";
              //echo "button1";
        $query = new Query;
                // compose the query
         $query->select('kpt_users.*,kpt_user_details.*,kpt_user_services.*')
                ->from('kpt_users')
                    ->join( 'INNER JOIN',
                        'kpt_user_details',
                        'kpt_user_details.user_id =kpt_users.id'
                    )
                    ->join( 'LEFT JOIN',
                        'kpt_user_services',
                        'kpt_user_services.user_id= kpt_users.id'
                    )


                    //->Where(['kpt_users.user_role_id' =>$role_id,'kpt_user_services.service_id'=>$service_id]) 

            ->limit(4);
                // build and execute the query
                $rows = $query->all();
                //var_dump($rows);exit;

         return $this->render('corporateinsurance', [
            'result' => $rows,
        ]);

         }

         if(isset($_GET['login-button3'])){
             //echo "kanak3";
              //echo "button1";
        $query = new Query;
                // compose the query
         $query->select('kpt_users.*,kpt_user_details.*,kpt_user_services.*')
                ->from('kpt_users')
                    ->join( 'INNER JOIN',
                        'kpt_user_details',
                        'kpt_user_details.user_id =kpt_users.id'
                    )
                    ->join( 'LEFT JOIN',
                        'kpt_user_services',
                        'kpt_user_services.user_id= kpt_users.id'
                    )


                    //->Where(['kpt_users.user_role_id' =>$role_id,'kpt_user_services.service_id'=>$service_id]) 

            ->limit(4);
                // build and execute the query
                $rows = $query->all();
                //var_dump($rows);exit;

         return $this->render('sbasedplanning', [
            'result' => $rows,
        ]);

         }

         if(isset($_GET['login-button4'])){
            // echo "kanak4";
             //echo "button1";
        $query = new Query;
                // compose the query
         $query->select('kpt_users.*,kpt_user_details.*,kpt_user_services.*')
                ->from('kpt_users')
                    ->join( 'INNER JOIN',
                        'kpt_user_details',
                        'kpt_user_details.user_id =kpt_users.id'
                    )
                    ->join( 'LEFT JOIN',
                        'kpt_user_services',
                        'kpt_user_services.user_id= kpt_users.id'
                    )


                    //->Where(['kpt_users.user_role_id' =>$role_id,'kpt_user_services.service_id'=>$service_id]) 
                    ->Where(['kpt_users.user_role_id' =>$role_id,'kpt_user_details.categori_id'=>$category_id]) 

            ->limit(4);
                // build and execute the query
                $rows = $query->all();
                //var_dump($rows);exit;

         return $this->render('taxplanning', [
            'result' => $rows,
        ]);

         }

    }
```

This is my view controller with the `foreach`-loop. When I am trying to print the record, the category ID is missing. How can I get all data *with* category ID?

```
<?php foreach ($result as $rows): 
$path =  Yii::$app->params['imagePath'];
// print_r ($rows);exit;

 ?>
   <?php $first_name = $rows['first_name'];
                    //echo $first_name;exit;
                $agency_name = $rows['agency_name'];
                $seller_name = $rows['seller_name'];
                $reff_no = $rows['reff_no'];
                $credentials = $rows['credentials'];
                $photo = $rows['photo'];
                $contact = $rows['contact'];
                //echo $contact;exit;
                $year_exp = $rows['year_exp'];
                $expertise = $rows['expertise'];
                $gender = $rows['gender'];
                $title = $rows['title'];
                $rnf = $rows['reff_no'];
                $user_name = $rows['user_name'];
                $user_email = $rows['user_email'];
                $first_name = $rows['first_name'];
                $user_id = $rows['user_id'];
                $user_role_id = $rows['user_role_id'];
                $service_id1 = $rows['service_id'];
            //print_r( $service_id1);
            //  $service_name = $rows['service_name'];
                $credentials = $rows['credentials'];
                //echo "User Name: {$user_name}" . "<br>"; 
                //echo "Ratings: {$rating}" . "<br>";
               // echo "RNF: {$reff_no}" . "<br>";
                //echo "Service Name: {$title}" . "<br>";
                //echo "Service id: {$service_id}" . "<br>";
                //echo "user role id: {$user_role_id}" . "<br>";
?>
       <div class="parent">
            <div class="col-lg-12 no-padding">
          <div class="col-lg-6">
            <div class="big-image">

<?php if($rows['photo']){ ?>
<img src=<?php echo $path; ?><?php echo $rows['photo']; ?> />
<?php } else { ?>
<?php echo Html::img('@web/images/banner/product-main.png'); ?>
<?php } ?>
            <?php //echo Html::img('@web/images/banner/product-main.png'); ?></div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-6">
            <div class="product-name">
              <h2><?php //echo $first_name?></h2>
               <h2><a target="_blank" href="index.php?r=userslisting/user&id=<?php echo $rows['user_id']; ?>"><?php echo $rows['first_name'];?></a> </h2>
            </div>
            <div class="rating-point">
              <p>Reating 4.5/5</p>
            </div>
            <div class="star"> 
            <span><?php echo Html::img('@web/images/banner/star-full.png'); ?></span>
            <span><?php echo Html::img('@web/images/banner/star-full.png'); ?></span>
            <span><?php echo Html::img('@web/images/banner/star-full.png'); ?></span>
            <span><?php echo Html::img('@web/images/banner/star-hafe.png'); ?></span>
            <span><?php echo Html::img('@web/images/banner/star-0.png'); ?></span> 
            </div>
            <div class="rating-point rnf">
              <p class="pro-title">RNF</p>
              <p class="pro-head-1"><?php echo $rnf?></p>
            </div>
            <div class="rating-point rank">
              <p class="pro-title">Rank/Title</p>
              <p class="pro-head-1"><?php echo $title?></p>
            </div>
            <div class="rating-point ss">
              <p class="pro-title">service specialzation</p>
              <p class="pro-head-1"><?php echo $expertise?></p>
            </div>
            <div class="rating-point creden">
              <p class="pro-title">Credentials</p>
              <p class="pro-head-1"><?php echo $credentials ?></p>
            </div>
            <div class="rating-point yoe">
              <p class="pro-title">Years OF Experience</p>
              <p class="pro-head-1"><?php echo $year_exp ?></p>
            </div>
            <div class="rating-point mail">
              <p class="pro-title">Email</p>
              <p class="pro-head-1"><?php echo $user_email; ?></p>
            </div>

            <div class="view-more">
            <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary serch-select view-more" value="ENQUIRE" name="ENQUIRE">


                          <div class="enquiry">
<?php if (Yii::$app->session->hasFlash('contactFormSubmitted')): ?>

        <div class="alert alert-success">

            Thank you for contacting us. We will respond to you as soon as possible.

        </div>
<?php else: ?>
<form id="contact-form" action="" method="post" role="form">

          <div class="form-group">
          <div class="col-lg-12 no-padding">
            <div class="name-1"><input type="text" name="name" class="form-control transparent" value="" placeholder="Name" required> </div>
           <div class="contact-1"><input type="text" name="contact" class="form-control transparent" value="" placeholder="Contact No." required> </div>
           </div>
           </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-lg-12 no-padding">
            <div class="email-1"><input type="email" name="email" class="form-control transparent" value="" placeholder="Email" required> </div>
            <div class="subject-1"><input type="text" name="subject" class="form-control transparent" value="" placeholder="Subject" required></div>
            </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group"><textarea name="message" class="form-control" rows="6" placeholder="Message"></textarea></div>

            <input id="form-token" type="hidden" name="<?=Yii::$app->request->csrfParam?>"
               value="<?=Yii::$app->request->csrfToken?>"/>

                    <div class="form-group submit-button">
<input type="hidden" name="user_id" value="<?php echo $rows['user_id']; ?>" />
<input type="hidden" name="user_name" value="<?php echo $rows['first_name'].' '.$rows['last_name']; ?>" />
<input type="hidden" name="user_email" value="<?php echo $rows['user_email']; ?>" />
                      <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="contact-button">

                    </div>
</form>
<?php endif; ?> 
</div>  


            </div>

          </div>



        </div>
         <div class="clear"></div>




    <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Here is my form

```
<div class="serch-select-premium">



              <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['action' =>['site/premiumsearch'], 'id' => '', 'method' => 'get',]); ?>

                 <?= $form->field($model, 'type_a_keyword')->textInput(['maxlength' => true, 'placeholder' => "Type a keyword"])->label(false); ?>

            <?= Html::submitButton('Personal Insurance', ['class' => '','id' => 'personalinsurance', 'name' => 'login-button1']) ?>
            <?= Html::submitButton('Corporate Insurance', ['class' => '','id' => 'corporateinsurance', 'name' => 'login-button2']) ?>
            <?= Html::submitButton('Solution Based Planning', ['class' => '', 'id' => 'sbasedplanning','name' => 'login-button3']) ?>
            <?= Html::submitButton('Tax Planning', ['class' => '','id' => 'taxplanning', 'name' => 'login-button4']) ?>
          <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>



        </div>
```

Comment: you don't have input with name 'categori_id' so how you want to get it?

Comment: Hi Thank's But  i required  cat id for my where condition at 
Controller  page 
if i use  $cat_id = $rows[''categori_id'];
echo $cat_id ; then i am Getting cat Id at my controller view page this is ok But 
 my where condition is at controller page 
so i am trying to get  $cat_id =Yii::$app->request->get('categori_id'); 
echo  $cat_id; so here unable to Get 
This is my where condition at 
Controller page
->Where(['kpt_users.user_role_id' =>$role_id,'kpt_user_details.categori_id'=>$cat_id) 
Thanks In advance...

Comment: ok, but your are trying to get categori_id from request GET which is fired by submitting form, so you must have input with name 'categori_id' inside your form to get his value using Yii::$app->request->get('categori_id')

Comment: I think you are not using Yii in a proper way. @Joint is right if you do not pass the category_id from the form then you can't get it, into the request.